Can't scrape data off table from a dynamic website
Okay, so I'm trying to scrape table off from this website - https://www.diamondsfactory.co.uk/design/combined-band-look-diamond-engagement-ring-clrn0717801
This section basically:Rows from the table
I've tried this script so far:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Open the webpage
url = "https://www.diamondsfactory.co.uk/design/combined-band-look-diamond-engagement-ring-clrn0717801"
driver.get(url)

# Find the table row by its id
row = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "tdStone  odd")

# Extract the data from each cell in the row
td_elements = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
data = [td.text for td in td_elements]

# Print the extracted data
print(data)

# Close the driver
driver.quit()


But, I'm getting this error -
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Payalkumavat\scrape_diamonds.py\scrape.py", line 17, in 
td_elements = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements'

find_elements() returns a list of elements, are you trying to get only the first element? also you need to click the Choose a specific > button to load the table.

Note: This answer contains a different method to reach your goal. (Module used: requests, JSON, time)
Based on your question I think you are trying to fetch all the information related to the tdStone class in html page. well, I found out there is a better way of solution than using selenium, here is my mindmap:-
Your target apps have an endpoint called index.php?route= (URL: https://www.diamondsfactory.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product/lazyloadDiamond) which acts as some kind of API route and fetches all the details from the server (all of this info then stored in tdStone class as HTML source), so if we send a request to specifying our goal (example: a diamond that meets your criteria) to this endpoint we can easily get those data with the help of python request library and a little bit of coding. here is my code:
Note: to avoid rate-limiting issues, I used time.sleep(3) to minimize the thread.
import json
import requests
import time
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def getData(content):
    loaded_content = json.loads(content)
    result = loaded_content['stones']
    for i in result:
        shape = i['shape']
        diamond_code = i['diamond_code']
        color = i['color']
        weight = i['weight_display']
        clarity = i['clarity']
        certificate = i['lab']
        image = i['image_url']
        polish = i['polish']
        symmetry = i['symmetry']
        price = i['csprice']
        video_url = i['video_url']
        mm = i['meas']
        depth = i['depth']
        table = i['table']

        print(f"Diamond Shape:  {shape}\nDiamond Color:  {color}\nDiamond Code:  {diamond_code}\nDiamond Weight:  {weight}\nDiamond Depth:  {depth}\nDiamond Table:  {table}\nDiamond MM:  {mm}\nDiamond Certificate:  {certificate}\nDiamond Image:  {image}\nDiamond Video:  {video_url}\nDiamond Polish:  {polish}\nDiamond Symmetry:  {symmetry}\nDiamond Price:  {price}\n====================================")

def sendRequest(url):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101"
    }
    for i in range(1,100):
        data = f"stone_type=LAB&ring_size=R16_7&metal_purity=GL_18K_W&stone_carat_min=0.20&stone_carat_max=30.00&stone_price_min=100&stone_price_max=5000000&&active_diamond_tab=LAB&page={i}"
        time.sleep(3)
        res = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False, headers=headers).text
        if '"stone_price_id":' in res:
            getData(res)
        else:
            break

sendRequest('https://www.diamondsfactory.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product/lazyloadDiamond')

If you're interested in only one response you can analyze these parameters to sort the response that meet your expectations &stone_shape=MQS&stone_carat_min=0.20&stone_carat_max=30.00&stone_clarity=&stone_color=&stone_certificate=&stone_cut=&stone_polish=&stone_symmetry=&stone_fluorescence=&stone_price_min=100&stone_price_max=5000000&show_image=&show_video=&show_instock=&show_heart_arrows=&markup=&tax_class_id=10&design_id=49&image_stone=di&side_stone=&metal_purity=GL_18K_W&product_id=15265&ring_size=R16_7&active_diamond_tab=LAB&diamond_code=&edit_product=&order=asc&search=&page=1
Some takeaways:

I didn't use any sorting method in my script, it is up to you.
If you want to sort those values then feel free to analyze the parameters I mentioned above.
what is the product_id? well after analyzing something with the URL you mentioned, I guess the product ID is the last five numeric digits of your mentioned URL. ( 17801 is the product_id of clrn0717801)
I used a loop to extract the maximum value that will meet your expectations. (I hope so : ()

Hope this will help
Thanks
